# An expression that means "speaking of X" or "while we're on this topic..."

Tags: grammar

I've been looking a way to introduce a topic when I think of something without just blurting out a new subject.

Say you're having a conversation about Oreos and how there used to be gingerbread Oreos (a real conversation topic I just had) and you wanted to say "speaking of things that are made with gingerbread, have you ever heard of X / there's this other thing."

Maybe "speaking of X" is a little different (I'm not entirely sure) like someone having a conversation about Donald Trump and you want to say "speaking of Donald Trump, have you heard about his scandal?" But maybe they're functionally the same.

Either way, is there an expression for this?　`Xを言えば`?

Comment: I think you're after Xと言えば

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary? I think this one should help: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/en/speaking+of/m0u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for "そう言えば" - I have definitely heard it used in situations like you mentioned, it it is usually translated as "Speaking of" or something similar. The most recent time I saw it, a women was talking about how the guy she liked was dragged to her house by her dad. Her friend jokingly asked if that meant she had parental approval, and then the first girl said "Speaking of, I was proposed to by (a different guy)." The phrase she used was そう言えば